# Kerberos Double Hop Delegation with ASP.NET Core (4.5.2)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, sql-server-2016, iis-10, windows-server-2016

Our dev, test and production environments all have similar setups using windows authentication and separate VMs for IIS 10 server and SQL Server 2016.  Both VMs running Windows server 2016.  All that remains is solving the double hop issue.

I haven't been able to find up-to-date how-to guides with steps needed to get this working, any help / recent references would be appreciated?

Here are some outdated how-to / checklists:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx#
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/taraj/2009/01/29/checklist-for-double-hop-issues-iis-and-sql-server/

and some outdated reference links:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2013/09/20/all-about-kerberos-the-three-headed-dog-with-respect-to-iis-and-sql/
- http://windowsitpro.com/security/how-windows-server-2012-eases-pain-kerberos-constrained-delegation-part-1

thanks, dave