# Double Hop Delegation: Error retrieving for user IIS APPPOOL. The underlying provider failed on Open. Login failed for user 'Domain\WebVM$'

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, sql-server-2016, iis-10, windows-server-2016

Double Hop Delegation: Error retrieving for user IIS APPPOOL. The underlying provider failed on Open. Login failed for user 'Domain\WebVM$'.

I'm setting up a IIS VM server to access a separate SQL Server VM, both machines running Windows Server 2016 and running on intranet.  We're using windows authentication, and attemping to impersonate users through the machine account on IIS VM server machine.  We are building / deploying MVC IIS bits using ASP.NET Core.

I'm hitting the above (machine account login) error after having configured everything I can think of and referred to several postings.  I've configured the following main items:

- Web Site setup with Windows Authentication, and ASP.NET Impersonation enabled, all other auth types disabled.
- Web Site Config Editor set "system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication" : useKernelMode to True
- App Pool running .NET CLR Version "No Managed Code"
- App Pool using Classic Managed Pipeline Mode
- App Pool running as ApplicationPoolIdentity
- Confirmed HOST SPN registered for IIS VM machine account in AD (with setspn -L IISVMServer)
- Confirmed HOST SPN registered for SQL Server VM machine account in AD
- Confirmed ServiceClass/Host:Port registered for SQL Server VM in AD
- Registered SPN for IIS server machine account "Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)

  - Plan to lock down to constrained delegation after getting unconstrained delegation working
- Tried running with / without web.config : "system.web identity impersonate="true" /system.web"

I previously posted [Kerberos Double Hop Delegation with ASP.NET Core (4.5.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976715/kerberos-double-hop-delegation-with-asp-net-core-4-5-2) which is indirectly related to this posting.

thanks, dave

Comment: frustrating much?! I can only suggest to carefully check the hostname in various places (i.e. SPN) as I believe 'hostname' is different to 'hostname.mydomain.local'.

Comment: Yeah frustrating indeed :).  I checked SPN and using FQDN as expected, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Dave, Did you ever have any luck with this? I am having similar problems ASP.net core on IIS10 but connecting to SqlServer 2012 the error is the same as you, `Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\iisvm$'`

Comment: Nope I never heard back, bit surprising considering I had considered this not atypical scenario.  Best of luck, hope someone answers so you can find your solution.